# Assistance with Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So what my code is supposed to do is get the student id's and put them into a dictionary and then get their homework, exams, and quiz grades also into the dictionary.

So it's supposed to look like

```
{'123456':{'exam':[97, 98, 45], 'homework': [44,45]} etc.
```

So for the sake of quickness i only added a portion to focus on the homework portion. How would i go adding that homework dictionary into the student id's dictionary? (The homework file has the student id followed by their grade)

```
def create_dictionary(idfilename, hwfilename):
    ids = open(idfilename, 'r')
    hw = open(hwfilename, 'r')
    d = {}
    grades = {}
    for i in ids:
        ids.readline()
        i = i.rstrip("\n")
        grades[i] = d
    for h in hw:
        x = hw.readline()
        x.split(' ')
        if h in grades:
            d = [i]
    print(grades)
```

Was i close?

Comment: We have no idea how the ids and hw files look like.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What input are you using, and what does the output look like? If you are getting any errors, what is the full text?

Comment: My question is how to insert the the hw grades into the student id dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785235/nested-dictionary).

Comment: Any example of input files?

Comment: @MattDMo my question is how do you insert the the hw grade into the student ID dictionary?

Comment: Without any idea of what your input looks like, we can't help you.

Comment: @Marcin The hw example [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn31mnbkd77352x/hwscores.txt?dl=0)

Comment: You didn't just post actual Social Security numbers of real students, did you?

Comment: [studentids](https://www.dropbox.com/s/id7vo0nl4lcj5uf/studentids.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Noooo lol all made up friend :) @MattDmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, as the form of your input data is unknown. But in general terms you could do as follows:

```
out_dict = {'123456':{'exam':[97, 98, 45], 'homework': [44,45]}}

# example of a list with grades. maybe read from a file?
homework_grades = [1,2,3,4]

# appends grades one at a time
for a_grade in homework_grades:
   out_dict['123456']['homework'].append(a_grade)

# or append all grades in one go.
out_dict['123456']['homework'] += homework_grades
```